# Progress bar while loading a heavy SVG graphic

Tags: javascript, svg

Good afternoon! Im looking for a progress bar that can track the loading progress of a very heavy svg graphic. The graphic takes around 10 seconds to load on IE and around 3 seconds on Chrome. Ive tried to use other javascript libraries that track loading progress on a website, but they seem to ignore completly the progress of the svg graphic. While loading, the browser seems completly unresponsive. Any ideas if this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: if the browser is unresponsive while downloading, it could be because you're using a synchronous download. If it's unresponsive while "rendering" the SVG, then there's no way a progress bar will help

Comment: Yes, im rendering the SVG myself, it's a heavy graphic with around 15,000 shapes. And yeah, its unresponsive while rendering/loading. Thanks for your comment! I was afraid i couldn't do anything about it.

Comment: when you say you're rendering it yourself, is the SVG dynamically created? My comment was regarding downloaded SVG that is then rendered by the browser, not some SVG that's dynamically created. With dynamically created SVG, of course you can have a progress bar

Comment: yes, it's dynamically created by my own algorithm. can you point me to the right direction? any function or script i could be using?

Comment: not right now, but at least it should be possible